# ng-options with multiple select/Checkbox

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-options, ng-modal

Is it possible to select multiple options from ng-options or have ng-options values as check boxes? If possible can someone give me an example please?

Comment: If you want examples, see the documentation for ng-options here. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @nageeb I think you didn't understand my question. I have a select bar with 5 options, right now I can select a single value from that dropdown, I want to select multiple values as a checkbox.

Comment: I understand your question.  However if you don't understand the multiple attribute, which is actually a property of the HTML Select tag, here's documentation on that as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a multiple select just add *multiple* to your select tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var app=angular.module("myApp", []);
   
           app.controller(
               "myCtrl", 
                    function($scope){
                        $scope.values=[
                            {value:"0", text:"zero"},
                            {value:"1", text:"one"},
                            {value:"2", text:"two"}
                        ];
                    }
               );
   
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div>Choose:</div>
            <select name="choose" ng-model="choose" multiple>
                <option ng-repeat="x in values" value="{{x.value}}">{{x.text}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @John Kane I just figured it out with your help. I can also use ng-dropdown-multiselect.